# Two versions of self object within class, how can this be?

Tags: python, class, self

I have been experimenting with a class that contains functions returning a generated class.

I want the generated class to have the 'self' object. It gets all attributes within self so I assigned 'self' to the generated self variable which I named 'own' to reduce confusion.

When assigning 'own' to 'self' python creates a second version of own and gives it a different id.
When calling the function the old 'own' gets returned.

```
import copy
from pprint import pprint


class test_class1(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number=number
        self.abc=['a','b','c']

    def test_class2(self):
        class test_class(object):
            def __init__(own):
                print('own id:')
                pprint(id(own))
                print('own attributes:')
                pprint(own.__dict__)
                print('\n')

                own=copy.deepcopy(self)
                print('own has selfs attributes own.number:',own.number)
                print('own id:')
                pprint(id(own))
                print('own attributes:')
                pprint(own.__dict__)
                print('\n')

        return test_class

a=test_class1(7).test_class2()()
print('own has no attributes anymore')
print('own id:')
pprint(id(a))
print('own attributes:')
pprint(a.__dict__)
print('\n')
```

The output is:

```
own id:
140178274834248
own attributes:
{}


own has selfs attributes own.number: 7
own id:
140178274834584
own attributes:
{'abc': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'number': 7}


own has no attributes anymore
own id:
140178274834248
own attributes:
{}
```

I have found a workaround but can someone explain why there are two versions of 'own' with different IDs and how I can only have one?

Comment: Do you just want instance `a` to have all of the same attributes as `test_class1(7)` after it's instantiated?

Comment: I'm very confused by your question but you aren't assigning `own` to `self` in the second class, you are just naming what would normally be called `self`, `own`. The variable name `self` is just convention in python, what ever you pass as the first parameter to `__init__` will be the name of the instance variable. What you end up with is making a `id(own)`, then `id(copy.deepcopy(self))` where `self` is from the outer scope, not the `self` you seem to be expecting from the second class

Comment: At the start of `test_class2.test_class.__init__()`, `own` points to the instance id `140178274834248` which is also pointed to in the global namespace by the name 'a'. In the namespace local to `test_class2.test_class.__init__()`, this line: `own=copy.deepcopy(self)` changes what the name `own` is pointing at, but it's not modifying the instance `id == 140178274834248`.

Comment: If you want `a` to have all of the same attributes as `test_class1(7)`, you could do something like `own.__dict__ = self.__dict__` in `test_class2.test_class.__init__()`

Comment: @SuperShoot I want instance `a` to have all the same attributes as `test_class2`. And `test_class2` gets all atributes from `test_class1`.

Comment: @liamhawkins I know I am just naming it `own` but then I would like`own` to have the same attributes as `self` from `test_class1`. I thought I could do that by just overwriting it with `own=copy.deepcopy(self)`. I understand the answer I was given by Sanyash, but I would like to know why there are 2 versions of `own` with different IDs.

Comment: There’s a second version because you create it with this line `own = copy.deepcopy(self)`. That creates a new object and assigns it to the name `own` but only within the scope of `__init__()`.

Comment: @SuperShoot So when `own=copy.deepcopy(self)` is called, what happens to `id==140178274834248` since it used to be the ID of `own` that was initiated by `__init__`. I assumed that overwriting `own` would change the ID and drop `id==140178274834248`.

Comment: It’s still there, and it’s still referenced by name `a` in the global namespace. It’s just not referenced by the name `own` anymore inside `__init__()`.

Comment: You said “.. since it used to be the ID of `own` that was initiated by `__init__`”. This is backward logic. The name `own` isn’t that ID, it only ever points to an object in memory that is represented by that ID. Changing the object that `own` points to doesn’t mean the original object ceases to exist, just that the name `own` is no longer referencing that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to replace `own=copy.deepcopy(self)` with `own.__dict__.update(self.__dict__)`. It will not change `id(own)` but will give all attributes of `self` to copied `own` object.

Code:

```
import copy
from pprint import pprint


class test_class1(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number=number
        self.abc=['a','b','c']

    def test_class2(self):
        class test_class(object):
            def __init__(own):
                print('own id:')
                pprint(id(own))
                print('own attributes:')
                pprint(own.__dict__)
                print('\n')

                own.__dict__.update(self.__dict__)  # here is the change
                print('own has selfs attributes own.number:',own.number)
                print('own id:')
                pprint(id(own))
                print('own attributes:')
                pprint(own.__dict__)
                print('\n')

        return test_class

a=test_class1(7).test_class2()()
print('own still has attributes')
print('own id:')
pprint(id(a))
print('own attributes:')
pprint(a.__dict__)
print('\n')
```

Output:

```
own id:
140228632050376
own attributes:
{}


own has selfs attributes own.number: 7
own id:
140228632050376
own attributes:
{'abc': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'number': 7}


own still has attributes
own id:
140228632050376
own attributes:
{'abc': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'number': 7}
```